# How I can use the same variable Session in two different Solution in .Net 4.5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session-variables

I have two different solutions where necessary to make switching between them. When I do that I keep a variable in session for the other side. But this is always empty when I change .

I can not pass this variable in the url or store in BD .

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

First Solution:

```
HttpContext.Current.Session["BlogUserEmail"] = utilizador.Email;
```

Second Solution:

```
string email = (string)System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["BlogUserEmail"];
```

I thank you.

Comment: Sessions are not shared between different "solutions" (sites).

Comment: @DStanley that is default... Custom session state can use other partitioning... (Also note that "user" in session state context has nothing to do with actual user but rather just browser's session).

Comment: But I can use a browser's session, right?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to share sessions, there is no simple way to do it, however you can implement something like this, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27090/Sharing-Session-Across-Applications, but keep in mind they need to be within the same application pool.